# GameObject not setting active to true in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MegatronAi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;

    public int speed = 5;
    public Player playerthing;
    public Animator anim;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Enemy enemy;
    public GameObject Scourge;  
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(enemy.dead){
            Scourge.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (playerthing.megatronCanMove)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        if (player.position.x > transform.position.x)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
            anim.SetBool("run", true);
        }
        else if(player.position.x < transform.position.x)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
            anim.SetBool("run", true);
        }
    }
}
```

When it checks whether the enemy is dead or not it doesn't work. Also I have checked if it is assigned or not and it does set the dead variable in the other script to true. Though the gameobject is a varient of another gameobject. Will that change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your dead enemy is the same enemy class that you have given as a reference

or just write that Scourge.SetActive(true) part inside the enemy class

Comment: Yeah It does set dead to true.

Answer (score 0):

What value have you given `enemy.dead`? Unless it is `gameObject.enabled` then just use that in this script, unless you want some custom behaviour. `gameObject.enabled` is the default unity field for the GameObject's status. If there is a direct corellation between that and `enemy.dead` then just use that.

Hope I could help!